# Swift: How can I change backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum with BGAppRefreshTask

Tags: swift, deprecated, ios13

I am changing my deprecated function `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval()` to new one `BGAppRefreshTask()` but every example is using actual-time like this:

```swift
request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60) // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now
```

but my current source used `backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` like...

```swift
UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

so how can I apply `backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` with `BGAppRefreshTask`?

Comment: Why does there have to anything analogous? BGAppRefreshTask Is a totally different architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the request’s `earliestBeginDate` is equivalent to the old minimum fetch interval. Just use `earliestBeginDate` like you have seen in those other questions. And when your app runs a background fetch, you just schedule the next background fetch with its own `earliestBeginDate` at that point. That is how `BGAppRefreshTask` works.

If you are asking what is equivalent to `UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum`, you can just set `earliestBeginDate` to `nil`. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskrequest/3142244-earliestbegindate) tells us that:

> Specify `nil` for no start delay.
>
> Setting the property indicates that the background task shouldn’t start any earlier than this date. However, the system doesn’t guarantee launching the task at the specified date, but only that it won’t begin sooner.

The latter caveat applies to `backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum`, too. Background fetch, regardless of which mechanism you use, is at the discretion of the OS. It attempts to balance the app’s desire to have current data ready for the user the next time they launch the app with other considerations (such as preserving the device battery, avoiding excessive use of the cellular data plan, etc.).

The `earliestBeginDate` (like the older `backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum`) is merely a mechanism whereby you can give the OS additional hints to avoid redundant fetches. E.g., if your backend only updates a resource every twelve hours, there is no point in performing backend refreshes much more frequently than that.